# Finding avenue that appears to no longer exist?

Tags: pennsylvania

Looking for what is at what used to be 2217 Nevada Avenue in McKeesport, Pa. 
My wife's grandmother lived there. City directories from the 50's and 60's listed her as living there, but Google maps shows only a Nevada Street in McKeesport now, not an Avenue. I assume perhaps a re-development of some sort has "deleted" Nevada Avenue.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE. Would you mind adding what you have already tried to search for this location, so we don't just tell you things you have already tried? Also, where does the location come from - for example, is it an address from a census record in the 1920s, or from a birth certificate in 1998? You can [edit] your question to add this information. The more detailed the question, the more useful an answer you will get.

Answer (score 3):

Google --- "nevada avenue" mckeesport --- and one of the top matches is [1955-vintage map - Tube City Online](http://www.tubecityonline.com/facts/documents/mckeesport_map_1955_a.pdf). On the 1955 map, Nevada Avenue ran between Elm St and Weber St, not far from S Duquesne Ave and 5th Ave.

By comparing this map and McKeesport on GoogleMaps, Elm Ave has been extended and modified and now overlays what was Nevada Avenue.

By the way, Nevada Ave was Ridge St before 1935, according to [Obtaining Street Name Changes in One Step](https://stevemorse.org/census/changes.html), specifically [STREET NAME CHANGES IN  MCKEESPORT, PENNSYLVANIA](https://stevemorse.org/census/changes/McKeesportChanges.htm). The source for this page ("from 1935 city directory") reminds that city directories include a section on street changes from the previous year.